# Minimum file permission needed to delete a file in Linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions

To delete a file in Linux,

- What minimal permissions do we need to set on it?
- What minimal permissions do we need to set on its parent directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have x-permissions and w-permissions on the directory (and of course x-permissions on all parents), that is all.

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/bar
chmod 300 foo
chmod 000 foo/bar
rm -f foo/bar
```

But when testing you might stumble into thinking that you need more (e. g. r-permissions for the directory or whatever).  This will be only due to false testing ;-)